# Fiddler AutoResponder - Regular Expression to ignore timestamp in URL

Tags: fiddler

I just start to use fiddler in my project for debug purpose, but haven't figure out how to handle following case with autoresponder :(

I need replace the timestamp in the request url then point to the my personal path, like

from http://www.test.com/static/20140828/js/test.js
to http://www.test.com/static/mycode/js/test.js,
while the timestamp "20140828" changing frequently so I hope can have a rule can match and handle this kind replacement automatically, without update the timestamp every time.

I tried the regex but not found the solution for this case.  Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that you need to use a regular expression; you haven't said what expression you tried.

You'll probably want to use something like:

**MatchText** `REGEX:^.*test\.com/static/\d+/(.*)$`

**ActionText** `http://www.test.com/static/mycode/$1`